# Is there a way by which we can train RNN without using one hot encoders?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to develop a sequential RNN for my log analysis projects.

Input is a log sequence say [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,5,2,7,8,2,1]

Currently i am using to_categorical function from keras library which converts a sequence to one-hot encoding.

````
def to_categorical(y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32'):
    """Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.

    E.g. for use with categorical_crossentropy.

    # Arguments
        y: class vector to be converted into a matrix
            (integers from 0 to num_classes).
        num_classes: total number of classes.
        dtype: The data type expected by the input, as a string
            (`float32`, `float64`, `int32`...)

    # Returns
        A binary matrix representation of the input. The classes axis
        is placed last.

    # Example

    ```python
    # Consider an array of 5 labels out of a set of 3 classes {0, 1, 2}:
    > labels
    array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
    # `to_categorical` converts this into a matrix with as many
    # columns as there are classes. The number of rows
    # stays the same.
    > to_categorical(labels)
    array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
    ```
    """

    y = np.array(y, dtype='int')
    input_shape = y.shape
    if input_shape and input_shape[-1] == 1 and len(input_shape) > 1:
        input_shape = tuple(input_shape[:-1])
    y = y.ravel()
    if not num_classes:
        num_classes = np.max(y) + 1
    n = y.shape[0]
    categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
    categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
    output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
    categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)
    return categorical
````

Problem which im facing is that there might be some logs which may not belong to the trained data lets say [9,10,11]

if i have a sequence of 2000 log keys & 275 unique logs.

There can always be unseen logs but if i want to save this model and reuse it on a new data , it may not be able to convert it to the same categorical format since the originally there were only 275 unique log classes in my RNN but now i have 275+ 3 new classes.

How do we tackle this problem?

Comment: how does google keyboard prediction work without knowing the entire vocabulary? It includes words from our custom vocabulary also. Do they not use RNN's to predict the sequence ? Dont they need to retrain their model if they see new words/classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding @Dainel's answer on class consistency, you can replace any value that doesn't appear in the training sequence with `np.nan` and use `pd.get_dummies` as follows.

```
train_seq = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
test_seq = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], dtype=np.float32)

test_seq[~np.isin(test_seq, train_seq)] = np.nan

df = pd.get_dummies(test_seq, dummy_na=True)
print(df)
```

which produces  a separate class for unseen data.

```
   1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  NaN
0    1    0    0    0    0    0
1    0    1    0    0    0    0
2    0    0    1    0    0    0
3    0    0    0    1    0    0
4    0    0    0    0    1    0
5    0    0    0    0    0    1
6    0    0    0    0    0    1
7    0    0    0    0    0    1
8    0    0    0    0    0    1
9    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: how does google keyboard prediction work without knowing the entire vocabulary? 

It includes words from our custom vocabulary also. 

Do they not use RNN's to predict the sequence ?

Dont they need to retrain their model if they see new words/classes ?

Comment: That's dealt by using methods like subwords. That is you learn the most common ngrams in your training corpus. (e.g. lower represented as low +er). With a big enough corpus you are able to represent unseen words in the test corpus.

Comment: How will it encode it since the newly added word from the personal dictionary does not belong to the training corpus. 

if the vocab size increases , the model which we had trained using one hot vectors of old vocab-size is of no use. 

We cant retrain the model everytime we see a new word. 

What i read online is the google use finite state transducers to do text generation but i need to read a bit more about it

Comment: This is a pretty interesting research topic. I think [this](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P16-1162.pdf) paper would be a good starting point. This is what I mentioned in the previous comment. Another method is to have a character level translator dealing with rare words within a word-level translator

Comment: the closest ive come to the solution is using lucene finite state transducer instead of using an RNN. It is fast and memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You must have class consistency, otherwise your model will simply not work correctly.

If the numbers make any sense numerically, you can use the numbers instead of one-hot. But since you say they're classes, they probably don't make sense.

You can try to separate a few train classes as unknown classes and group them into a single one-hot encoding. Then all new classes will receive this same encoding.

But it's not guaranteed that the model will give you good results.